# Altering a table with a new column that allows only 3 different values iSQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I am trying to alter a table "tutor" with a new column "subject" that allows only 3 different values: "reading", "math", "ESL".

What I have so far:

```
ALTER table tutor
add subject varchar2 (10) 
         CHECK ('reading', 'math', 'ESL');
```

I keep getting this:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ALTER table tutor
add subject varchar2 (10) 
add constraint sb CHECK(subject IN ('reading', 'math', 'ESL'));
```

Comment: thanks kind sir/ma'am, i have to remember to separate the constraint.